# How to check if a value is on a list, and if it is change another value on the same row

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

Basically, I am trying to do some data cleaning. I am working in a data set of a bike sharing company that list every trip made on its system. There are columns for station name and station id for every ride, but in many rows the station_name is badly written.

I would like that every row in station_name had the same value for every id in station_id, but right now 5 different names are common for every id, and there are hundreds of ids.

I managed to create a new dataset that looks something like this:

| station_id | station_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1032 | Public Rack - Kedvale Ave & 63rd St |
| 1033 | Public Rack - Pulaski Rd & 65th St |
| 1038 | Public Rack - Kedzie Ave & 62nd Pl |
| 1039 | Public Rack - Kedzie Ave & 61st Pl |

...

It list all the id's and station names once. I would like to do so that r checks the main dataset, checks the id there, then checks the id on this new dataset and reeplaces whatever it is in the main station_name with the station_name of this new dataset.

Any help is appreciated, I honestly have no idea where to start.
If anyone knows how to do this using the tidyverse's packages that would be amazing. It's what I am currently using.
Also, if there's a better aproach than what I did already please let me know.

Comment: You’ll want to use a merge, e.g. with dplyr, `original_data %>% select(!station_name) %>% left_join(corrected_names)`.  See this thread: [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.